# How to acess to my global properties in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript, typescript1.5

I have a few functions in my .ts file, to have an access from a function to other functions and to global variables, I do: `var self = this`, and then self. - and a I have an access to all my fucntions and variables. 
 But:
 Having a problem with knockout binding in following example: 
 
`<span data-bind="text: CatNom", click: $parent.ClickedItem />` and in my 
 `public ClickedItem(obj, event) { var self = this }` - and here, **this** is my obj in parameter. 
 How to declare this as a instance of my class to have an access to all my properties in my entire class. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an arrow function and you don't need to even create a `self` variable:

```
clickedItem = (obj, event) => { 
    console.log(this) // `this` is the class instance
}
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: thank you for the useful link. I'm very new to TypeScript, so very often I'm having problems.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Used lambda expression. 
 So **I have:**

```
public ClickedItem = (obj, event) => { var self = this }
```

**Instead of**

```
public ClickedItem(obj, event) { var self = this }
```

[TypeScript and Knockout binding to 'this' issue - lambda function needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277537/typescript-and-knockout-binding-to-this-issue-lambda-function-needed/13285438#13285438)